# mainframe internals

Tags: mainframe, internals

Can anyone tell me links for reading about mainframe internals like what happens in mainframe intrenally when I login or create a dataset or submit a job. I googled but couldnt find

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The [Principles of Operation](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/a227832c.pdf) will give you as low-level a look at mainframe internals as you're likely to get.

You mention wanting to know what happens internally "when I login or create a dataset or submit a job."  You might want to ask yourself, "login to what?" exactly.  [TSO](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-tsoe)? [CICS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6)?  [IMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ims/15.2.0)?

For creating datasets you might start with [DFSMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-dfsms).

For submitting jobs you might want to start with [JES2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-jes2) or [JES3](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-jes3), depending on which one you're using.

None of what you're asking is a small topic.

Answer (score 0):

A mainframe is fundamentally just like any other computer - it is just a matter of scale that differentiates a mainframe from a desktop. Fundamentally, what happens when you log in to a Windows desktop is very similar to what happens when you log in to a mainframe. The details are very different but fundamentally you are doing the same thing.

The links [cschneid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727120/192510) provided in his answer will give you a lot of the finer detail, but conceptually, what goes on inside a mainframe is similar to what goes on in any computer these days.

Comment: If by 'mainframe', people are actually referring to an IBM mainframe running the z/OS (a.k.a. OS/390 & MVS) operating system, then the answer is that z/OS is fundamentally UNLIKE any other common OS (Windows/OS X/*nix). For an glimpse of these differences, try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042879/hasp373-and-ief403i-z-os-syslog/26523925#26523925